# How to get my flutter app to realize that it was started with a different intent?

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

I have a Flutter app which, like a browser, can be started from either the launcher or through a URI intent.

I have two files. The Dart file containing the main code and the Kotlin file containing the intent catching code.

My Kotlin code looks like:

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        print("got at resume ${intent.data}")
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        print("At onCreate: ${intent.data}")
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
        MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            print("got at onCall ${intent.data}")
    }
}
```

So when I start it the first time, it outputs `At onCreate: null"`. Makes sense, I started it without an intent.

Then I run `adb shell am start  -d "https://www.example.com"`. I expect it to (and when I wrote a demo Android app, it did) output `print("At onCreate: https://www.example.com")`.

However, when I run it as a Dart app, I get `FlutterActivityDelegate: onResume setting current activity to this`. Even when I send it to background and then run `adb shell...`, I get `got at resume null`.

The only way for me to get `At onCreate: https://www.example.com` was to remove it from the previous app list. Then, and only then did I get the right output.

But even then, running `adb shell am start  -d "https://www.example.com/123"` produces the same bug as above.

How can I get the "new" intent in Dart/Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *AndroidManifest.xml* the `android:launchMode` is relevant. If it's set to `singleTop`, the `Activity` will receive a call to [`onNewIntent(Intent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)):

> Note that `getIntent()` still returns the original Intent. You can use `setIntent(Intent)` to update it to this new Intent.

Comment: It's more complicated then that, as it's not pure android but Flutter project instead

Comment: Your `MainActivity` is not flutter related. `onCreate` is only called once and to get an updated intent in `onResume` you need to implement `onNewIntent`.

Comment: But the point of this question is to know this _inside flutter_. Not on the native android part. They don't communicate with each others like that.

Comment: _Flutter_ only knows what your activity knows before. `FlutterActivity` is just delegating the lifecycle events to `eventDelegate`. Anyway you have to update `onNewIntent()`. Regardless of doing so within the activity or as implementation of `FlutterActivityEvents`.